# Offers to download an empty file when opening the main page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to open a finished project locally. I downloaded the files and the database and tried to open them using OSPanel. But when I go to the main page it offers me to download an empty file and that’s it. My local url is http://ctcarehomehealth/.

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ctcarehomehealth.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://citycarehomecare.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddType x-font/svg .svg
AddType x-font/otf .otf
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddType x-font/eot .eot
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/png .png
AddType image/jpg .jpg
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg
# END Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

# BEGIN CACHING 
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
</ifModule>
# END CACHING

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

[image: File structure]

Comment: `# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit` - sounds like you copy&pasted that from the live system, but it is likely not applicable to your local setup. Remove the complete block after this.

Comment: I deleted this block but still offers to download the file when entering the main page

Comment: If you rename the .htaccess to something else to temporarily disable it, can you properly request _any_ PHP file then?

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I delete a file, it still offers me to download the file. I don't understand where this is coming from

Comment: Sounds like there is probably something wrong with your "OSPanel" setup to begin with.

Comment: It’s strange, because before this all my projects were opened. There is a problem with this specifically.

Comment: _"even when I delete a file, it still offers me to download the file"_ - wait, are you talking about a .php file here, and not the .htaccess? Then likely either your browser has cached a previous redirect for that URL - or you are not actually in the correct directory. What is the document root for your local `ctcarehomehealth` domain set to?

Comment: Sorry, what is document root

Comment: The document root is where your local domain actually points to, the folder in your file system.

Comment: My main folder is called ctcarehomehealth. It contains a WP project

Comment: And the folder content from your screenshot, is what that `ctcarehomehealth` folder contains, yes? Can you access a static file like `http://ctcarehomehealth/license.txt` then, or does that not work either?

Comment: Yes, this is my folder contents. When I try to access http://ctcarehomehealth/license.txt, I get a message - Server error!
A server error occurred and the server was unable to process your request. The server is overloaded or an error has been detected in the CGI script. Error 500
There is an entry in the logs: . htaccess: Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: That directive is part of `mod_filter`, so you will either need to add this module, or remove those lines from your .htaccess. (Since they are only about applying compression to static resources, it should not matter too much in a local dev setup, when this gets removed.)

Comment: After I removed these lines, I can now access ctcarehomehealth/license.txt and it loaded. But on the main page it still offers to download an empty file